# SQL Stuff from Subquery

Tags: sql-server

I have a query that returns a list of services and ContractorIDs.  I need to stuff these services into a field to join them with another select statement by ContractorID, but I can't figure out how to do it.

The Select that lists the services is "

```
    SELECT DISTINCT SM.ContractorID,

CASE WHEN S.bitRestrictedSelection = 1 
        THEN S.vchDescription + '*'
        ELSE S.vchDescription
    END AS vchDescription
FROM tblAscServiceRegionToOperator SRTO 
INNER JOIN tblServiceMatrix SM 
    ON SRTO.OperatorID = 12624
    AND SM.ServiceRegionID = SRTO.ServiceRegionID
    AND SM.bitPrimaryService = 1
INNER JOIN tblServices S
    ON S.ServiceID = SM.ServiceID
```

This produces the following:

[image]

In the example, for Contractor #16  He has 4 services I need to put them in one field called services by joining with another Select statement 
I tried the following, but I get errors:

```
    Select DISTINCT CompanyID, vchCompanyName as CompanyName,vchFIDNumber,vchPrimContactName, vchPrimContactEmail 
,stuff((','
    SELECT DISTINCT 
    SM.ContractorID,

        CASE WHEN S.bitRestrictedSelection = 1 
            THEN S.vchDescription + '*'
            ELSE S.vchDescription
        END AS vchDescription
    FROM tblAscServiceRegionToOperator SRTO 
    INNER JOIN tblServiceMatrix SM 
        ON SRTO.OperatorID = 12624
        AND SM.ServiceRegionID = SRTO.ServiceRegionID
        AND SM.bitPrimaryService = 1
    INNER JOIN tblServices S
        ON S.ServiceID = SM.ServiceID
        FOR XML PATH('')
                ), 1, 1, '') as Services from tblCompany
```

Any assistance is greatly appreciated!!!

Comment: Look up "Common Table Expressions" (CTEs), as it allows you to encapsulate a sub-query so that it just seems like a table, and can really help simplify your SQL code. It makes joining a lot easier.  Breaking a problem down into individual CTEs and then joining them back to build up the query you want can be a very useful approach.

Comment: What errors do you get?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following query would work:

```
SELECT SS.contractor Contractor,
       STUFF((SELECT '; ' + US.vchdescription 
              FROM ServicesList US
              WHERE US.contractor = SS.contractor
              FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '') [Services]
FROM ServicesList SS
GROUP BY SS.contractor
ORDER BY 1
```

I have created a table and inserted there two rows for contractor = 16, for you to get the idea. 
You can use the suggestion given to you in the comments, to wrap the first select into a `CTE` and then perform the `STUFF` function on that `CTE`.

You can check a demo of this query [here](http://rextester.com/GIROQT75394).